# Select * from table where id=(a lot a different values)...how to write a query that can do this function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables register and bar which are linked with the field id_register.I have the following query

```
$query="select * from register where register.id_register=(select bar.id_register from bar where bar.confirm='1' AND bar.confirm2='0') ";<br><br>

$run=mysql_query($query);<br>
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run))<br>
{ 
    echo " $row[id_register]." ; <br>
    echo " $row[another-field]." ;  
}
```

I need help to solve this  problem :
This query release an error because when search for register.id_register **(where register.id_register=(select bar.id_register from bar where bar.confirm='1' AND bar.confirm2='0'**) founds a lot of id values on DB.
How can i solve this? Is there another mysql function that i can use to select data in the right way??

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IN** clause here.

> The IN  operator allows you to determine if a specified value matches any one of a list or a subquery. The following illustrates the syntax of the IN  operator.

**Reference:** http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT 
  column1,column2,...
FROM
  table_name
WHERE 
  (expr|column_1) IN ('value1','value2',...);
```

**Try this:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE register.id_register IN (SELECT bar.id_register FROM bar WHERE bar.confirm='1' AND bar.confirm2='0') ";
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please up vote and accept my answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Mark the question as solved or people will stop helping you

Answer (score 0):

As you need to fetch data from 2 tables "register" and "bar" by joinng two columns you can better use JOIN query .

For reference

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and a helper table.

```
SELECT aa.*
FROM `register` AS aa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bar.id_register
    FROM bar
    WHERE bar.confirm = '1' AND bar.confirm2 = '0'
) AS bb
ON aa.id_register = bb.id_register;
```